# HighChart tooltips different with yaxis dateformat

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I've a problem using highchart. 
in yaxis dateformat it doesn't problem , but in tooltip dateformat, it is give me different for 1 hour.

JS :

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Report Due Date vs Surat Jalan',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'PT BKA',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        title: {
            text: 'So No'
        },
        labels :{
            rotation: -45
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
            day: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'  },
        labels :{
            formatter:function() {return  Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',this.value);}
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br><b>' + this.series.name +'</b> : ' + 
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',this.y);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: []
};
```

JSON data form PHP :

```
1: {name: "SODate", data: [1457910000000]}
data: [1457910000000]
name: "SODate"
2: {name: "DeliverDate1", data: [1457996400000]}
data: [1457996400000]
name: "DeliverDate1"
3: {name: "DeliverDate2", data: [1458169200000]}
data: [1458169200000]
name: "DeliverDate2"
4: {name: "DeliverDate3", data: [1458255600000]}
data: [1458255600000]
name: "DeliverDate3"
```

ToolTip :

```
SODate : 1 457 910 000 000
DeliverDate1 : 1 457 996 400 000
```

but when using formatter like first script , it's showing different 1 hour different

```
SODate in yaxis : 14/03/2016 00:00:00
SODate in Tooltip : 13/03/2016 23:00:00
```

I am already using

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: { useUTC: false }
 });
```

but it just make more big different.
Why this can happen?

UPDATE 15 March 2016 :

After using global: {   timezoneOffset: 7 * 60, useUTC: false }
its not make different, because yaxis is not problem.

[image]

After using global: {   timezoneOffset: -60, useUTC: true}
it works, but it is right?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to specify http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.timezoneOffset ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/oL3LfrLr/4/

Comment: the datetime displayed depends on the timezone of the client machine. use the method suggested by llamerr to display datetime values in a specific time zone